# Hangman program in python 3.x

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
print("Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!")

words= ['utopian','fairy','tree','monday','blue'] 

i=int(input("Please enter a number (0<=number<10) to choose the word in the list: "))

if(words[i]):
    print("The length of the word is: " , len(words[i]))


guess=input("Please enter the letter you guess: ")


if(guess in words[i]):
    print("The letter is in the word.")

else:
    print("The letter is not in the word.")

guesses=1

while guesses<6:
    guess=input("Please enter the letter you guess: ")


if(guess in words[i]):
    print("The letter is in the word.")
    guesses=guesses+1

else:
    print("The letter is not in the word.")
    guesses=guesses+1

if guesses==6:

    print("Failure. The word was:" , words[i])
```

Just started on this Hangman program in python. I'm doing this on a step by step based on a set of instructions and I'm at the point where I want to write some simple code that checks whether the letter entered is found in the chosen word at all. I'm ignoring the position of the matches, only concerned with counting the number of bad guesses. So far so good it seems, but I've encountered a small but big (if that makes sense) problem. On the sixth **bad** guess I want the loop to finish and let the user know that they failed and the computer won. I noticed that in my case the loop finishes once the user has entered their sixth guess, whether it be bad or good. So if the word is 'fairy' or whatever, no matter how many correct letters that the user guessed the loop will finish regardless on their 6th go. I want the loop to finish only when the user has entered six bad guesses, so in the example of the word 'fairy' if the user inputs 'f' which would be correct and if the next six guesses are incorrect the "failure" message will be printed as opposed to what I have now.

Comment: How about you count the correct and incorrect guesses separately?

Comment: Jon Clements is right. You're counting guesses period, not only bad guesses. You need to not increment the guess variable when the letter is in the word.

Answer (score 1):

You have this code:

```
if(guess in words[i]):
    print("The letter is in the word.")
    guesses=guesses+1
```

If you remove that last line, then good guesses won't be counted against you.

Also, I'd be careful about your whitespace. The way you have the question now, only the one `guess=input("Please enter the letter you guess: ")` line is in the `while` loop. I'm guessing that is a simple mistake putting the code on StackOverflow, though.

Answer (score 1):

It's a slightly unconventional answer, but here's some edited code with commentary.

```
print("Welcome to Hangman! Guess the mystery word with less than 6 mistakes!")

words= ['utopian','fairy','tree','monday','blue'] 

i=int(raw_input("Please enter any number to choose the word in the list: "))%5
#the %6 here means divide the input by six and take the remainder as the answer. I found the instructions a little confusing, and this allows the user to be competely unrestricted in the number that they choose while still giving you a number (0, 1, 2, 3, or 4) that you want. Increasing the number after the % will give you a larger variety of choices.

# if(words[i]):
#this line is unnecessary with the above code, and also would not prevent errors futher along in the code if i was not a number between 0 and 4.

print "Your chosen word is", len(words[i]), "characters long."
# slight wording change here
#guess=input("Please enter the letter you guess: ")
#if(guess in words[i]):
#print("The letter is in the word.")
#else:
#print("The letter is not in the word.")
#guesses=1
# all of this is already accomplished in the loop you wrote below.

incorrect_guesses = 0
# it's always nice to initialize a variable
while incorrect_guesses<6:
    guess=str(raw_input("Please enter a letter to guess: "))
    # Unless you're using python 3, I would use raw_input rather than input.


    if((guess) in words[i]):
        print('Correct! The letter "' + guess + '" appears in the word ' + str(words[i].count(str(guess))) + ' times.')
    else:
        print('Sorry, the letter "' + guess +
              '" is not in the word.')
        incorrect_guesses=incorrect_guesses+1
# Plusses instead of commas clean up the output a bit, and str(words[i].count(str(guess))) gives you the string form of the number which indicates how many times the guess appears in the word. This is useful in words like "tree".
print("Failure. The word was:" , words[i])
# This is outside the while loop because it gets triggered as soon as incorrect guesses go over 6.
# You can still improve the program by adding a feature which tells the players that they have guessed all of the correct letter and telling them what the word was, and possibly by increasing the word list. You can also tell players when they have already guessed a letter in case they've forgotten.
```

Hopefully this will be helpful to you in your future python endeavors.